# Public Route53 CNAME Record to Private API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53, amazon-vpc

## Background

I have a Private API Gateway attached to a VPC Endpoint which I am *NOT* using private DNS for.  Therefore the url of the form `https://${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.this.id}-${aws_vpc_endpoint.this.id}.execute-api.${var.region}.amazonaws.com/${var.stage}/${var.path}` is **publicly resolvable** per [Invoke Private API via VPC Endpoint with Route 53 Alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-api-test-invoke-url.html#w17aac15b9c32c26c13).  This is an endpoint used by other internal clients at my org who are coming from within our private, multi-cloud network.

I can successfully invoke this URL no problem from my private network with the following:
`curl -v -X POST https://${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.this.id}-${aws_vpc_endpoint.this.id}.execute-api.${var.region}.amazonaws.com/${var.stage}/${var.path}`.

## The Necessary Design

This URL will change whenever the api gateway id or vpc endpoint id changes.  I need a **static** url I can provide to internal clients that will **never change**.

## Attempted Solution

I create a route53 CNAME record named `endpoint.sub.domain.com` in a public hosted zone called `sub.domain.com` and pointed it at `${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.this.id}-${aws_vpc_endpoint.this.id}.execute-api.${var.region}.amazonaws.com` to serve as a static "proxy" to always point to the underlying publicly resolvable DNS record for the Private API Gateway.

## What happened

I went to curl this just like the previous one and received:
`curl -v -X POST https://endoint.sub.domain.com/<stage>/<path>`
but had TLS issues:

```
Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
*  start date: Sep 19 00:00:00 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Sep 16 23:59:59 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName does not match endpoint.sub.domain.com
* SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'endpoint.sub.domain.com'
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):
curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'airport-mock-endpoint.npd.nortonalto.com'
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Tried the same with `--insecure` just to see:
`curl --insecure -v -X POST https://endoint.sub.domain.com/<stage>/<path>`
And received `{"message”:”Forbidden”}`.

Tried the same, this time specifying the api gateway id:
`curl --insecure -v -X POST https://endoint.sub.domain.com/<stage>/<path> -H "x-apigw-api-id:5xxxxxxf"`
And received:
`{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}`

Tried the same, this time specifying the target of the CNAME record (the original url) as the **Host**:
`curl --insecure -v -X POST https://endoint.sub.domain.com/<stage>/<path> -H "Host: {api-gateway-id}-{vpc-endpoint-id}.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"`
And received:
**Success!**

## The Problem

### Clients must be able to call this API **without passing in the Host header** AND **with the same secure TLS that the original endpoint provides**.  How can this be accomplished?

---

#### Possible solutions

##### 1. Have a server 302 redirect requests

- Don't know if this would solve all the problems
- NOT elegant as I want to accomplish this purely from DNS

##### 2. Configure something involving Cloud Front?

##### 3. Some Route 53 / API Gateway DNS configuration?

##### 4. Enable private DNS in my VPC

- Would solve the problem but would introduce the problem of [not being able to call public api gateways from this network](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-vpc-connections/) (as private DNS would "swallow" these queries)
- Requires more network complexity I wanted to avoid by using a public DNS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Api gateway will serve your "static" domain certificate only via feature called "custom domains" which is not supported for private api gateways. See first blue note box in this aws documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html

The only available solution I'm aware of is described here in aws github https://github.com/aws-samples/serverless-samples/tree/main/apigw-private-custom-domain-name

This solution works around this limitation by creating network load balancer in front of your private api gateway which can be configured to use your "static" domain certificate.

Comment: This does seem to be the best/only workaround, thanks for the answer.